# Prove: there exist a unique group homomorphism $\bar{f}: G_1/H_1 \to G_2/H_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, universal-property

I am trying to solve the following problem:

For $i = 1,2,$ let $G_i$ be a group and $H_i$ be a normal subgroup of $G_i.$ Let $\pi_i: G_i \to G_i/H_i$ be given by $\pi_i(a) = a H_i$ for all $a \in G_i.$ Let $f: G_1 \to G_2$ be a group homomorphism such that $f(H_1) \subset H_2.$ Let $f': H_1 \to H_2$ be the restriction of $f.$

$(a)$ Prove: there exist a unique group homomorphism $\bar{f}: G_1/H_1 \to G_2/H_2$ such that $\bar{f} \circ \pi_1 = \pi_2 \circ f.$

I understood that we are trying to prove that the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G_1 @>{\pi_1}>> G_1/H_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
G_2 @>{\pi_2}>> G_2/H_2
\end{CD}$$

But still I do not know how to define a function to help me in this proof, could someone help me please?

Comment: Verify that $H_1\leq\ker(\pi_2\circ f)$ and apply the Fundamental Theorem of homomorphisms.

Comment: Why should I do these two steps?

Comment: Because you want to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment , I understood @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Are you planning to fix the formatting of your post?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do not know what is making it looking like this

Comment: The fact that you are posting LaTeX (like, `\documentclass`, `\end{document}`, etc) rather than mathjax might have something to do with it. And that it wouldn't compile as a LaTeX document (you have an `\end{document` but no `\begin{document}`, for example) would be a clue...

Comment: Ok, let me see how can I fix it .... @ArturoMagidin thanks for the clarification

Comment: MathJax [does not support tikz](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34337/742). [Here are some ways to draw commutative diagrams with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/742).

Comment: How can I verify that $H_1 \leq \operatorname{ker}(\pi_2 \circ f)$?@ArturoMagidin

Comment: Geez... maybe by reading the assumptions you are making about $H_1$, $H_2$, and $f$? For example, the part that says "**such that $f(H_1)\subset H_2$** "?

Comment: I guessed that this part is really what will prove it but I did not know quite well why it prove this @ArturoMagidin let me think more

Comment: What is the kernel of $\pi_2$? So what happens when you apply $\pi_2\circ f$ to an element of $H_1$?

Comment: The kernel of $\pi_2$ is $H_2$ @ArturoMagidin

Comment: This means that $\pi_2$ will be applied to an element in $H_2$ as $f(H_1) \subset H_2$ @ArturoMagidin and so we will be in the kernel of $\pi_2$ ..... right?

Comment: Will that give me also intuition on how to define the required map $\bar{f}$? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: The fundamental theorem of homomorphisms tells you how to define the map.

Comment: Let me think how is that :)

Comment: Got it thank you very much :) @ArturoMagidin